# Issues with rotating jqueryUI modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to build **a modal that rotates to a particular element**, `$(.linkmoddet)`, based on a clicked element in the navbar `$('.selectcircle')` using the `.switchClass` function in *jQueryUI*.

However, I am having issues with the actual math involved, often causing:

- only one or two elements to rotate at a time.
- multiple elements gaining classes but not losing them.
- occasionally losing all the classes involved, defaulting the element in question to a standard size and position in CSS.

**Code**

**Edit:** This has now been fixed.

http://codepen.io/yeasayer/pen/ZWxYZG

```
var selectcircle = $('.selectcircle');
var linkmoddet = $('.linkmoddet');
selectcircle.click(function(){
    var circleindex = $(this).index()-1;
    var centerindex;
    console.log(circleindex);
    selectcircle.each(function (index){
        if (circleindex == index)
        {
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
    linkmoddet.each(function (index){
        if ($(this).hasClass('moddetcenter'))
        {
            centerindex = $(this).index();
            console.log("the center is index #"+centerindex);
        }
        var rotation = centerindex - circleindex;
//This is where I start having issues.
        var i = $(this).index() + rotation;
        var j;
        if (i <= -1)
        {
            j = i + moddetids.length-1;
            $(this).switchClass(classes[i+$(this).index()],classes[j]);
        }
        if (i >= moddetids.length)
        {
            j = i - moddetids.length;
            $(this).switchClass(classes[i-$(this).index()],classes[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (rotation < 0)
            {
                j = i-1;
            }
            else
            {
                j = i+1;
            }
            $(this).switchClass(classes[i], classes[j]);
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve the desired results, possibly in a simpler manner than described above?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it turns out that I figured it out by doing the following:

```
linkmoddet.each(function (index){
        var classnum;
        var newrot;
        if ($(this).hasClass('moddetcenter'))
        {
            classnum = 2;
            if (rotation < 0)
            {
                rotation += classes.length;
            }
            if (classnum + rotation >= classes.length)
            {
                newrot = classnum + rotation - classes.length;
                $(this).switchClass(classes[classnum],classes[newrot]);
            }
            else if (rotation != 0)
            {
                $(this).switchClass(classes[classnum],classes[classnum+rotation]);
            }
        }
/* This is repeated for all the classes available in the classes array.
 * ie: 0 being the first class, 1 being the second, etc. It's not an 
 * elegant solution, but it works for my current needs at the moment  
 * while I put it in a function in the future. */
```

Thanks!